# Is there a citation style with just the first author's last name, and year

Tags: citation-style

Is there citation style that only cites it as (FirstAuthorLastName,year)
that can be downloaded as a .csl file and incorporated into mendeley/readcube.

However a simple nature style [1] is too short.
And I would like to see the author's name in the text.
Is there citation style that only cites it as (FirstAuthorLastName,year)

Meaning no other coauthors name, (since that not how I remeber the article anyway) and no et al.
(because i already know it's "et al", it's just redudant text).

is there a citation style that is like this?.

Or is there a website when one can see different citation syles?

Thanks

Comment: If you're just writing quick notes, why do you need to follow an established style?

Comment: Ideally it would be implemented in readcube, mendeley, or papers, any type of .csl file, e.i a citation style, than can be searched in a reference manager.

Comment: I guess I don't follow what you're trying to do

Comment: You can define your own style in mendeley or endnore and I'm pretty sure in most of the reference managers.

Comment: I favour BibTeX's _alpha_ mode, which produces citations such as [Cam07], which provides many of the advantages of (Campbell, 2007), but is more compact.

Comment: I understand the appeal, in my oppion its a bit too sparse information. 
or in other words, if i was to remeber the citation (i.e the reverse, where you lookup an article from memory of the citation),  if I then wrote cam07 into mendeley or readcube, it might not be able to find it, whereas Campbell, 2007 would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a comment you mentioned that you're looking for a .csl citation style file, e.g. for use with Mendeley. It turns out that Mendeley has a generator for, and repository of such files. In particular, one can opt to [search by example](https://csl.mendeley.com/searchByExample/). Using that tool for citations of the form "(Campbell, 2007)" reveals some examples, the most relevant of which is [a modified Chicago style](https://csl.mendeley.com/styleInfo/?styleId=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2Fstyles%2Fcolorado-state-university-school-of-biomedical-engineering) that appears to be associated with Colorado State University - School of Biomedical Engineering:

> ### Example Output
>
> **Inline citations**
>
> (Campbell, 2007)
>
> (Ahlquist, 2009; Borges, 1999; Campbell, 2007; Mares, 2001)
>
> **Bibliography**
>
> Ahlquist, J. S., & Breunig, C. (2009). Country clustering in comparative political economy (MPIfG Discussion Paper No. 09–5) (p. 32). Cologne: Max-Planck Institute for the Study of Societies. Retrieved from www.mpifg.de/pu/mpifg_dp/dp09-5.pdf
>
> Borges, J. L. (1999). Selected non-fictions. (E. Weinberger, Ed., E. Allen, S. J. Levine, & E. Weinberger, Trans.). New York: Viking.
>
> Campbell, J. L., & Pedersen, O. K. (2007). “The varieties of capitalism and hybrid success.” Comparative Political Studies, 40(3), 307–332. https://doi.org/10.1177/0010414006286542
>   “CSL search by example.” (n.d.). Retrieved December 15, 2012, from http://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/
>
> Mares, I. (2001). “Firms and the welfare state: When, why, and how does social policy matter to employers?” In P. A. Hall & D. Soskice (Eds.), Varieties of capitalism. The institutional foundations of comparative advantage (pp. 184–213). New York: Oxford University Press.

I have not tried it myself, but I hope it does the trick.

Comment: Thank you, perfect - and search by example is a helpful tool for others who are in need of a different style.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with anyon. Well, that's the basic citation style and it is the mostly used. Since you said that your doing a quick not, this will style will be okay for your writing.
..this site might help..
http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/citation/apa/intextcitation/